# Copy contents of Downloads to newly created folder with Applescript

Tags: macos, applescript

I have the below code, which works to copy the contents of Downloads to the desktop. What I would like to do is copy it to the newly created folder, the `folder_name`, which is the current date and time.

```
set folder_name to (current date)
set folder_name to folder_name as string

tell application "Finder"
    set p to path to desktop
    make new folder at p with properties {name:folder_name}
end tell

tell application "Finder"
    move (files of alias "Macintosh HD:Users:XXXXX:Downloads") to desktop
end tell
```

Essentially, I'm not sure how to pass `folder_name` into the final path. I tried `(desktop & folder_name)`

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `make new folder` command of the Finder returns the new folder.

And there is a relative path to the Downloads folder of the current user

```
set currentDate to (current date) as string
set downloadsFolder to path to downloads folder

tell application "Finder"
    set currentFolder to make new folder at desktop with properties {name: currentDate}
    move (files of downloadsFolder) to currentFolder
end tell
```

Comment: Another question. if I wanted to create the folder on an external SSD. How is that accessed?

Comment: Sorted it: `set diskName to "SSD"` then swap `desktop` to diskName

Comment: `make new folder at disk "DiskName"`